# capture the number iwth comma or dot with regex

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have regex code

https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/8

As you see this code

```
(?<!\S)(?<![\d,])(?:(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020))\d{4,}[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?![\d,])[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?!x)(?!/)
```

can capture all digits which sperated by 3 digits in text like

- "here is 100,100"
- "23,456"
- "1,435"

all more than 4 digit number like without comma separated

- 2345
- 1234 " here is 123456"

also this kind of number

- 65,656½
- 65,656½,
- 23,123½

The only tiny issue here is if there is a comma(dot) after the first two types it can not capture those. for example, it can not capture

- "here is 100,100,"
- "23,456,"
- "1,435,"

unfortunately, there is a few number intext which ends with comma...can someone gives me an idea of how to modify this to capture above also?

I have tried to do it and modified version is so:

```
(?<!\S)(?<![\d,])(?:(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020))\d{4,}[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?![\d])[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?!x)(?!/)
```

basically I delete comma in (?![\d,]) but it causes to another problem in my context 
it captures part of a number that is part of equation like this :

4,310,747,475x2
 57,349,565,416,398x.

see here:

https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/10

I know that is kind of special question I would be happy to know your ides

Comment: You should use `(?!,?\d)` instead of `(?![\d,])`. Also, `(?<!\S)(?<![\d,])` looks redundant, as `(?<!\S)` requires a whitespace or start of string and that is certainly not a digit or `,`. Either use `(?<!\S)` or `(?<!\d)(?<!\d,)` - what is your left-hand boundary requirement?

Comment: Well, the `[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?!x)(?!/)` at the end might also be a problem: do you want to fail `65,656½x` totally or just extract `65,656`?

Comment: You seem to avoid matching years, but you just fail all numbers that start with them, so `2020222` won't get matched. Add `(?!\d)` - `(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020)(?!\d))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your comments, first one works perfectly good!  I want to have   65,656½ which works now after the edition baes on your first comment

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that `(?![\d,])` fails any match followed with a digit or comma while you want to fail the match when it is followed with a digit or a comma *plus* a digit.

Replace `(?![\d,])` with `(?!,?\d)`.

Also, `(?<!\S)(?<![\d,])` looks redundant, as `(?<!\S)` requires a whitespace or start of string and that is certainly not a digit or `,`. Either use `(?<!\S)` or `(?<!\d)(?<!\d,)` depending on your requirements.

Join the negative lookaheads with OR: `(?!x)(?!/)` => `(?!x|/)` => `(?![x/])`.

You wnat to avoid matching years, but you just fail all numbers that start with them, so `2020222` won't get matched. Add `(?!\d)` to the lookahead, `(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020)(?!\d))`.

So, the pattern might look like

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020)(?!\d))\d{4,}[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?!,?\d)[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?![x/])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/11).

**IMPORTANT**: You have `[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?![x/])` at the end, a negative lookahead after an optional pattern. Once the engine fails to find the match for `x` or `/`, it will backtrack and will most probably find a partial match. If you do not want to match `65,656` in `65,656½x`, replace `[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?![x/])` with `(?![\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?[x/])[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?`.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/12).